# after changing code and saving them the debugger show the termination window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Java, Selenium, and TestNG to write a test. that would be very convenient for me if I could run the test on debug mode so whenever I need to do some changes I will do save them and there will be no need to run from the beginning. the problem is that when I apply changes in the test body (the method that has @test) and save them, instead of going somewhere before the lines that I changed it shows me the window that says terminate, restart, etc.
what is the regular way of using debug in TestNG?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to start debugging a test, and then edit the code while the execution is paused, and then continue without starting over.

While some debuggers have gotten smart enough to be able to recompile your code changes mid run, depending on what the changes were, this is usually not possible. If you make some changes, you'll most likely have to stop the test, and restart it from the beginning. This is because the program has to be recompiled to include your changes.